# Cannot find the specified test-execution-json:

Tags: azure-devops, specflow

I have this specflow demo project which I can run successfully locally.

[image]

But when I import it at Azure DevOps, it says  `Cannot find the specified test-execution-json:`

[image]

This is my configuration

[image]

This is my repo - https://github.com/ngaisteve1/SpecFlow_Runner

Comment: Is it just a typo on the path you specified?  Your local you say is working is SpecFlow_Runner/SpecFlow_Runner.

Comment: so what should I put in azure devops settings?

Comment: Just going off your local copy, maybe $(BuildSourcesDirectory)/SpecFlow_Runner/SpecFlow_Runner/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/TestExecution.json

Comment: One thing you can do also is to run a local Azure DevOps agent.  You could target your build against the agent.  I have done this in the past where I get build failures that work locally.  Usually, it will be pretty obvious when you inspect the working folder on the agent what is missing or if there is folder structure differences than the pipeline expects.

Comment: Could you post the output of the Test task?

Comment: Can you please share the configuration of the Test task?

Answer (score 0):

When you add an repo to a Azure devOps pipeline as an artifact / Repo, it usually creates an "Alias" and you will need to use that alias in your path.

[image: Image for artifact alias]

Then you can use this alias for the path for example:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_tempAlias/FilePath/File